# Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException' in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to learn using EWS API. I want to retrieve all the appointments from my calendar.

I used the following technique to get the appointments:

```
CalendarFolder folder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
CalendarView view = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate);
FindItemsResults<Appointment> results = folder.FindAppointments(view);
```

Assume that the startDate and endDate are given.

My code keeps crashing at **WellKnownFolderName.Calendar**

And I get this exception:

> 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException' in
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

The ErrorCode is '**ErrorImpersonateUserDenied**'
The Message is **The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user.**

But I am trying to access my account only with the EWS API.
And I cannot give delegate access to myself from outlook.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are specifying the right credentials?

Comment: Yes. The way above is to access the mailbox using a Delegate Access. But The error message I get is about Impersonation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn641957(v=exchg.150).aspx I'm finding it difficult to understand why it gives an Impersonation error for a delegate access technique.

Comment: I can perform other operations, like send email, or schedule an appointment using the API. It works perfectly fine. But I cannot get access to any of my folders from the API itself. I keep getting the ImpersonatedError above.